# Support on 3rd party SSDs for Lenovo ThinkSystems

Tags: ssd, lenovo

I was wondering if there are any problems on using third-party NVMe-SSDs (e.g. Samsung 970) in a Lenovo ThinkSystem?

Comment: Could someone please explain me as a new part of the community the downvotes? What is the difference to e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/867287/hp-proliant-dl360-g8-g9-with-samsung-pm863a-ssds?rq=1

Comment: Hi, for such questions, for hardware on workstation, are more ontopic for superuser, while the question you linked is for server hardware. This is the main differance. It would had been on topic if you ask us on an IBM xSerie in exemple

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad: I wrote ThinkStation instead of ThinkSystem. My question refers to ThinkSystems - the server line!

Comment: Shame on me :-)

Comment: Np :) I will reopen as it's on topic, but please edit to include the model number and some research you did. As we have no idea of the raid controller you have, the generation of the server, etc.. (It could be closed as unclear)

Answer (score 4):

Workstation are not “so sensible” for enemy hardware as servers. So, if it has NVMe M.2 slot, you can use any compatible. Lenovo also uses branded Samsung NVMe (for example 4XB0N10299).

As for the warranty, check it with local Lenovo representative.